# Does a tap to click mouse exist

Tags: mice, touchpad

There are a few 'touch' mice out there with tap for 3rd button (e.g. Arc Mouse) and capacitive scroll. But I haven't seen any that have tap-to-click for left and right button functions (like on a trackpad). Most seem to use mechanical switches.

(The Samsung SMT-7000B *might* have tap for primary click, but I can't even tell)

If interested, I have finger fatigue (RSI), but a touchpad is not a great solution for me.

Comment: Are you looking for something like Apple's Magic Mouse?

Comment: something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-3KJ-00001-Touch-Mouse/dp/B004HYGU18

Comment: @NoahL both Apple and Microsoft use mechanical switches for clicks. They are only touch for gestures (scroll, swipe, etc). They generally do this so that the mice will function as basic mice without software or OS support.

Comment: @DanV as stated above, except with the addition of right click

Comment: Have you considered a [vertical mouse](https://www.google.com/search?q=vertical+mouse)? They orient your wrist a different way from a normal mouse.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I use a vertical mouse. It does not address the issue at all.

Comment: @Frank Would taking the switches out of an ordinary mouse and putting them in pedals, somewhat like one for guitar effects or a sewing machine, be an option?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'd advise against. I tried that and couldn't walk for a few days. [Can I use a foot pedal to send mouse clicks and/or modifier keys ergonomically?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/25/43)